# Entity Framework not creating MigrationHistory table

Tags: .net, entity-framework, migration, subquery, code-first

I have an MVC (.Net v4.5.2) website project with a Models project (EF v6.1.3) in a solution. Our DBA created an **empty** database for me, and I'm trying to enable Code First Migrations for it. Other than not needing the DB created, I want to use everything the Migrations has to offer, but I'm apparently missing something or have something configured incorrectly. When I enable Migrations, the folder and config files are cretaed fine. When I create a Migration it is created just fine. When I update the database, it is not.

It is my understanding that the MigrationHistory table should be created during my first Migration. This is not the case. I've turned on Migration Logging so I could see what is happening.

In the Package manager Console, this is what is happening:

Enable-Migrations - Ok.
Add-Migration Initial - Ok.
Update-Database:

> Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
>       Applying explicit migrations: [201612022154381_Initial].
>       Applying explicit migration: 201612022154381_Initial.
>       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>       The statement has been terminated.
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinNewTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass30.<ExecuteStatements>b__2e()
>          at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
>          at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>          at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__b()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
>          at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>          at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
>       ClientConnectionId:30d22ebc-78b5-4525-82bc-3d62f0d95ac2
>       Error Number:512,State:1,Class:16
>       Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>       The statement has been terminated.

And the logs:

```
Opened connection at 12/2/2016 1:54:50 PM -08:00
select cast(serverproperty('EngineEdition') as int)
-- Executing at 12/2/2016 1:54:50 PM -08:00
-- Completed in 33 ms with result: SqlDataReader

Closed connection at 12/2/2016 1:54:50 PM -08:00
Opened connection at 12/2/2016 1:54:50 PM -08:00
IF db_id(N'Portal') IS NOT NULL SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT Count(*) FROM sys.databases WHERE [name]=N'Portal'
-- Executing at 12/2/2016 1:54:50 PM -08:00
-- Completed in 33 ms with result: 1

Closed connection at 12/2/2016 1:54:50 PM -08:00
Opened connection at 12/2/2016 1:54:50 PM -08:00
IF db_id(N'Portal') IS NOT NULL SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT Count(*) FROM sys.databases WHERE [name]=N'Portal'
-- Executing at 12/2/2016 1:54:50 PM -08:00
-- Completed in 33 ms with result: 1

Closed connection at 12/2/2016 1:54:50 PM -08:00
Opened connection at 12/2/2016 1:54:50 PM -08:00
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ContextKey] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
-- p__linq__0: 'Models.Migrations.Configuration' (Type = String, Size = 4000)
-- Executing at 12/2/2016 1:54:50 PM -08:00
-- Failed in 34 ms with error: Invalid object name 'dbo.__MigrationHistory'.

Closed connection at 12/2/2016 1:54:51 PM -08:00
Opened connection at 12/2/2016 1:54:51 PM -08:00
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
-- Executing at 12/2/2016 1:54:51 PM -08:00
-- Failed in 34 ms with error: Invalid object name 'dbo.__MigrationHistory'.

Closed connection at 12/2/2016 1:54:51 PM -08:00
Opened connection at 12/2/2016 1:54:51 PM -08:00
Started transaction at 12/2/2016 1:54:51 PM -08:00
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] (
    [MigrationId] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [ContextKey] [nvarchar](300) NOT NULL,
    [Model] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    [ProductVersion] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.__MigrationHistory] PRIMARY KEY ([MigrationId], [ContextKey])
)
-- Executing at 12/2/2016 1:54:51 PM -08:00
-- Failed in 38 ms with error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

Disposed connection at 12/2/2016 1:54:51 PM -08:00
```

It attempts to access the MigrationHistory table, and finding that it does not yet exist, attepmts to create it. And somewhere in there it considers something a subquery... and fails. Someone 'splain this to me.

UPDATE: This is my context:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace Models
{
    public class SiteContext : DbContext
    {
        public SiteContext() : base("SiteContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your context class details ?

Comment: I've added a copy of the entire Context class.